# Cannot create working Remote Hybrid Android app with Mobile SDK 4.1

Tags: sfdcmobilesdk-android

I've been trying for days now to get a working Remote Hybrid Android app to build for Android using the current (4.1) build of the Salesforce Mobile SDK.  I've made some progress (I think), but remain stuck.  This is a log of my progress so far.

Using `forcedroid` to create an app skeleton currently results in errors, as [has been documented in the Salesforce Mobile SDK Google Group](https://plus.google.com/114386294177040037145/posts/fgqtK7CWqLr).

```
nvm use v0.12.2
forcedroid create --apptype=hybrid_remote --appname=sdktest --targetdir=. \
--packagename=org.jclark.sdktest --startpage=/apex/BasicVFPage
```

eventually leads to:

```
Fetching plugin "phonegap-plugin-push" via npm
Installing "phonegap-plugin-push" for android
Failed to install 'phonegap-plugin-push':Error: Variable(s) missing: SENDER_ID
    at /Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:346:23
    at _fulfilled (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Failed to install 'com.salesforce':Error: Variable(s) missing: SENDER_ID
    at /Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:346:23
    at _fulfilled (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:749:13)
    at /Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:557:44
    at flush (/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
Error: Variable(s) missing: SENDER_ID
```

If you attempt to run the app now (`cordova run android`), the app will build and run, however, you'll get a `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/index.html`popup, which I would not expect from a Remote hybrid app.

However, the error text indicates that the push plugin was not installed correctly, and looking at the command output and the source of `forcedroid` convinced me that some of the installation steps are being skipped when the plugin install fails.  Some folks in the MobileSDK Google Group reported removing the new `phonegap-plugin-push` and adding the older salesforce push plugin, but I could not get a working build this way, so I set out to fix the underlying `forcedroid` error.

The root issue is that the new push plugin, `phonegap-plugin-push`, expects a variable SENDER_ID to be defined, containing the Android Push Notification Client Id; the [plugin installation docs](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md) show the variable being passed as part of the `cordova plugin add` commandline. Unfortunately, the push plugin isn't added with that command.  Instead, `forcedroid` adds the plugin [SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin), which lists the push plugin as a dependency in its `plugin.xml`.  A little experimentation showed that I could add the variable to the dependency declaration in such a way that it would use an ENV variable of the same name.  [I forked the plugin and made that change](https://github.com/jclark-dot-org/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/commit/cd09e9c75277149ddc3d5e3fd23654e32a607570), then edited my local `forcedroid` (in my case, `/Users/jclark/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.2/forcedroid` to change the `plugin add` line:

```
//shelljs.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin#v' + version);
shelljs.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/jclark-dot-org/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin');
```

With this change in place, running `forcedroid` with a SENDER_ID ENV variable declared:

```
SENDER_ID=0000000000 forcedroid create --apptype=hybrid_remote --appname=sdktest --targetdir=. --packagename=org.jclark.sdktest --startpage=/apex/BasicVFPage
```

Runs without error.  Running the app (`cordova run android`) will succeed like the first test (app runs, cannot find `index.html`), but further experimentation has shown that there's still an issue with the basic app framework... the `after-platform-add-android` hook of the Salesforce plugin (plugins/com.salesforce) never runs.  This script makes some changes to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, such as commenting out the first `<application>` tag found - presumably so that it can be replaced by the version in the Salesforce plugin's `plugin.xml` file.  Adding any plugin will fire this hook, and then running `cordova prepare android` will cause `AndroidManifest.xml` to be updated.  For example:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-badge
cordova prepare android
```

Now an attempt to build the app will fail:

```
:processDebugManifest
/Users/jclark/sdktest/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:30:9 Error:
    Element activity#com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity at AndroidManifest.xml:30:9 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:6:9
/Users/jclark/sdktest/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:0:0 Error:
    Validation failed, exiting
```

The reason for this is somewhat complicated, but this is what I've determined: when the `after-platform-add-android` hook runs, it removes the first `<activity>` tag from `AndroidManifest.xml`, which the salesforce plugin replaces (see above), however, this changes the order of the tags within the `<application>` tag.  The `activity` which is removed and replaced is the "primary" activity (containing `android:name="com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.ui.SalesforceDroidGapActivity"`); It is originally the first child of `application`, but after the manifest is updated it becomes the last child.  This makes `<activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" />` become the first child.  Then the cordova `prepare` step updates the first `activity` element found to set the `android:launchMode` explicitly, so the activity becomes `<activity android:exported="true" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity" />`.  However (and this is where I'm theorizing based on empirical evidence), it looks like the build process is re-writing the manifest by adding missing items; since it expects the version without `android:launchMode="singleTop"`, it ends up adding it again.  I tried to work around this by adding `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to the main `activity` in the `plugins.xml` file (a change which remains in my fork, since it was in the original activity), but that doesn't stop this from happening.  Since I didn't want to fork the push plugin to change the plugin.xml to add the launchMode attrib, the workaround I've found is to manually edit the `android.json` file to add it there.  Then I remove all of the of the contents of `<application>` from the manifest, and run `cordova prepare android` to rebuild the manifest.

This moves past the prior error, but fails with:

```
/Users/jclark/sdktest/platforms/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/sf__icon').
```

I addressed this with one more change to my fork of the SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin, by updating the `after-platform-add-android` hook to change `sf__icon` to `icon`.

So at this point, I can set the ENV var `SETTING_ID`, run my custom `forcedroid` which uses [my fork of the SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin](https://github.com/jclark-dot-org/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin), add a plugin, run prepare, modify platforms/android/android.json to add android:launchMode=\"singleTop\" to the `com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity` line, and run `prepare` once more to get a project that will build.  However, when I run it on device, I immediately get "Unfortunately the application has stopped".  `logcat` shows the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009): Process: org.jclark.sdktest, PID: 5009
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.jclark.sdktest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.jclark.sdktest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4327)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5027)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.jclark.sdktest-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.jclark.sdktest-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5009):        ... 11 more
```

The key bit of course is `Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp"`.  It appears that the app is being built without all of the SDK components included.  At this point I've exhausted my knowledge of the Cordova/Android build process.  I tried adding the SDK libs directly to `platforms/android/project.properties`, e.g.:

```
android.library.reference.2=SalesforceSDK
android.library.reference.3=SalesforceHybrid
android.library.reference.4=SmartStore
android.library.reference.5=SmartSync
```

But that just led to more build errors; I'm thinking that I'm going in the wrong direction there... the plugin is part of the project, so I shouldn't need to add explicit references.

At this point, I'm not sure what to try next. My ideal solution would be a working `forcedroid` that can build a working Hybrid Remote android app from scratch, supports push, and continues to work when other plugins are added.  Once I have a set of steps to do this, I can work on my original problem of porting an existing SDK 3.x project to SDK 4.1.  I will be cross-posting this to the SDK Google Group as well.

**Update 3/22**: On the [Salesforce MobileSDK Google Group thread for this post](https://plus.google.com/106416138732002084790/posts/RHKzqZXFgdt), SDK Dev Bharath Hariharan pointed me to a recent commit in the `unstable` branch of the Cordova Plugin that addresses the first issue (push plugin errors) by pinning the versions of all dependencies.  I updated my local forcedroid to use the latest unstable commit:

```
//shelljs.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin#v' + version);
//shelljs.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/jclark-dot-org/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin');
shelljs.exec('cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin#a45425d8e831c9567a0d0bf8b05bc3e1b19b4f23');
```

This fixes the first problem (push plugin errors).  While testing this, I found that for some reason the android post install script wasn't finding shelljs, so I added it locally as suggested in the script error message (`npm install shelljs@0.5.3`); this allowed all post-run scripts to run successfully during the `forcedroid` run, and eliminates the need to add another plugin to get a fully updated `AndroidManifest.xml`.  So at this point, I can run the updated `forcedroid` using the latest unstable SDK Cordova plugin, run `cordova prepare android` to cause the duplicate activity issue, and manually add the launchmode to the push activity in `android.json` and remove the resulting duplicate activity in AndroidManifest to get a build that will install on the device.  It still crashes on launch with the `Didn't find class "com.salesforce.androidsdk.phonegap.app.HybridApp"` exception.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that if my project includes plugins other than the SF one then I need to make sure that I add the SF one last. I have mentioned this in one of the [git issues](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Android/issues/1074). At the time of writing I still have to follow the process of removing the plugin and platform and then re-adding both, only this way do I not end up with a duplicate issue in the manifest.xml.

As an aside yes the push plugin update to v1.6 was a right pain ;-)

Comment: We have to do this same process, readding the SF plugin last